# GeoJSON - Method within onEachFeature

Tags: vuejs2, leaflet

[Vue2Leaflet](https://github.com/KoRiGaN/Vue2Leaflet) is a library to implement Leaflet into the Vue2 Framework; with the ability to show GeoJSON objects on a map.

With multiple GeoJSON lines, I want to have a mouse click event that effects the style of other lines (e.g. it toggles a `selectedLineId` variable). I managed to change the style of geojson lines on mouse over itself; see this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jwdobken/qywaz1h8/67/).

Core is the `onEachFeature` which adds the mouse over event to every feature. But I have no idea how to run a Vue method from here;

```
function onEachFeature (feature, layer) {
    layer.on('mouseover', function (e) {
        e.target.setStyle({
            color: "#FF0000"
        });
    });
    layer.on('mouseout', function (e) {
        e.target.setStyle({
            color: "#000000"
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) your `onEachFeature` function to your Vue object:

```js
data() {
    return {
        // ...
        lines: {
            geojson: geojsondata,
            options: {
                onEachFeature: onEachFeature.bind(this),
                style: {
                    color: "#000000"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`this` in `onEachFeature` will then reference your Vue object:

```js
function onEachFeature (feature, layer) {
    var v = this;

    layer.on('mouseover', function (e) {
        // assuming you have a getColor method defined
        e.target.setStyle({
            color: v.getColor()
        });
    });
    layer.on('mouseout', function (e) {
        e.target.setStyle({
            color: "#000000"
        });
    });
}
```

Here's an updated Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/qywaz1h8/96/

Comment: tnx, but seems like the method is only ran during initialization

Comment: In my example, yes, since `onEachFeature` is called on initialization  and not on mouse events. I've modified the example to show how you can reference the Vue object on mouseover.

Comment: helped me a lot already! now I only need to change the style of objects dynamically ([my current Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jwdobken/qywaz1h8/110/))